# Github Api - Access Organizational Repositories with personal AccessToken

Tags: github, github-api

With the following url I can post new releases to a repository of mine.
With the personal access_token I can grant the required permissions

```
https://api.github.com/repos/myUser/myRepo/releases?access_token=dasdasdsfdsffsdfdsfs23131
```

But When the repository is owned by an organization this seems to not work and I get a 404 as result ( I assume that the access_token doesn't suffice here).

I'm the company administrator so the user permissions should be enough.

are there any hints what must be differenz when looking at organizational repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Admin/Owner permission for that repo?

Comment: yes . i found it out half an hour agao. I made a mistake when creating the token. It had only permission for public repos. As your answer is closely realted i'll mark it as an answer